# Zend Form File Validation Ajax

Tags: ajax, forms, file, validation, zend-framework

I would validate a form before submit, but using Zend_Form_Element_File the function isValid() return false (because this is only a string, the filename).

There is a solution to skip this validation and demand it after the form submit? I try to remove all validators (also setRequired(FALSE)) with the same results.

The function processAjax() return error without message (array()) and I don't use isValidPartial() because the validation is true also if other element required is null.

Can anyone help me? Excuse for my english!

Comment: check out http://samsonasik.wordpress.com/2012/10/11/zend-framework-2-using-zend-form-and-ajax/

Comment: check out http://www.zendcasts.com/ajaxify-your-zend_form-validation-with-jquery/2010/04/

Comment: Hi @TomPHP, the link you are provided is not helping me... I already have a validation with ajax, but the question is "how do i skip FILE element (Zend_Form_Element_File) from the function isValid() when I validate the complete form?". This is a problem because the validation fails when no $_FILES variables are present (only on submitted form). Otherwise thank you for helping me!